# A supposed unique instance of an object is changing all the time. [Solution found: use Spark Accumulator to avoid concurrency behavior with threads]

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am running a test that is willing to see how many records of a dataset have null values for each field, in order to ensure I am declaring my schema with the correct nullable indicators.

```java
@Test
@DisplayName("Tester la nullité des champs")
void nullite() {
   DatasetChecker checker = new DatasetChecker();
   Map<String, Double> champs = checker.tauxNullsParChamp(this.ressourceJeuDeDonneesDataset.rowCatalogueRessources((Verification[]) null), false);
}
```

I have a `Dataset<Row> candidat` with a schema having fields.

```java
public Map<String, Double> tauxNullsParChamp(Dataset<Row> candidat, boolean ignorerNonNullables) {
   long count = candidat.count();
   Map<String, Double> tauxDeChampsNulls = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   if (count == 0L) {
      LOGGER.warn("Le dataset soumis pour comptage de champs nuls n'a aucun enregistrement : le comptage ne peut avoir lieu.");
      return tauxDeChampsNulls;
   }

   LOGGER.info("Il y a {} enregistrements dans ce Dataset.", count);

   StructField[] fields = candidat.schema().fields();

   final Map<String, Long> nombreDeChampsNulls = new HashMap<>();
   candidat.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>)row -> compteNulls(nombreDeChampsNulls, row,  fields, ignorerNonNullables));

   if (nombreDeChampsNulls.isEmpty()) {
      LOGGER.error("Le dataset n'a aucun champ");
   }
[...]
```

and this method is called for each row:

```java
private void compteNulls(Map<String, Long> nombreDeChampsNulls, Row row, StructField[] fields, boolean ignorerNonNullables) {
   for(int index = 0; index < fields.length; index ++) {
      StructField field = fields[index];
       // Si le champ est nullable d'après le schéma et qu'on nous demande de l'ignorer, passer au suivant.
      if (ignorerNonNullables && field.nullable()) {
         continue;
      }

      Long nombreDeNulls = nombreDeChampsNulls.computeIfAbsent(field.name(), k -> 0L);

      // Détecter un champ null et le compter.
      if (row.isNullAt(index)) {
         nombreDeChampsNulls.put(field.name(), nombreDeNulls + 1L);
      }
   }
}
```

Debugging it, it executes only one
`final Map<String, Long> nombreDeChampsNulls = new HashMap<>();`
and one
`DatasetChecker checker = new DatasetChecker();`
as expected.

But putting a breakpoint on `if (ignorerNonNullables && field.nullable())` shows me a `nombreDeChampsNulls` changing pointer all the time.

For example, this will come during the debug session:

[image]

And then, later, in the same debug running:

[image]

That, because my `this` object, the `DatasetChecker checker` instance, has changed between each sub method `compteNulls`: from `Datachecker@28199` to `Datachecker@28280`, in example.

And at the end, the test fails on:
`LOGGER.error("Le dataset n'a aucun champ");`

If I change the two `DatasetChecker` methods to static, I have an equivalent behavior, targeting `nombreDeChampsNulls` that still change for each row iteration.

But how is that possible that the `checker` instance (or the `nombreDeChampsNulls` instance in the second case, with static) change, if they are only instantiated once? One unique time, by a specific `new` for each, alone, and not in a loop.

Comment: How is WHAT possible?  I can't tell what you are questioning.

Comment: @Hulk: therefore, my question could be "_Why could some keys could be removed from my Map_, then. As I'm not doing any remove or putting null value into (if this would have a removal effect).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25782057/can-we-have-a-nested-map-as-key-within-other-map

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the information displayed in the debugger - it is not a "pointer". Instead, it is the output of [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.html#hashCode()) - the part after the `@` is simply the hashcode. For collections, this depends on the data they contain.

`LinkedHashMap` and `HashMap` are documented to use the implementation in [`AbstractMap.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractMap.html#hashCode()), which is documented to use [`Map.Entry.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#hashCode()). It uses both key and value. The hashcode of a `Map` changes when its contents (keys and/or values) change.

Answer (score 0):

**Epilog:** You are right, I'm misleading often with that hashcode...

But if I not able to understand clearly the spark behavior, I've detected that I was inside a story of threads.

Using a Map, how I've done, was very dangerous and unsafe.

I had to change to `LongAccumulator` instead.

```java
/**
 * Renvoyer le taux de champs null par nom de champ.
 * @param candidat Dataset à analyser.
 * @param ignorerNonNullables true pour ignorer ceux qui sont déjà marqués comme non nullables dans le schéma.
 * @return Map de champs avec leur taux
 */
public Map<String, Double> tauxNullsParChamp(Dataset<Row> candidat, boolean ignorerNonNullables) {
   long count = candidat.count();
   Map<String, Double> tauxDeChampsNulls = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   if (count == 0L) {
      LOGGER.warn("Le dataset soumis pour comptage de champs nuls n'a aucun enregistrement : le comptage ne peut avoir lieu.");
      return tauxDeChampsNulls;
   }

   LOGGER.info("Il y a {} enregistrements dans ce Dataset.", count);
   StructField[] fields = candidat.schema().fields();

   SparkContext ctx = candidat.sparkSession().sparkContext();
   Map<String, LongAccumulator> accumulateurs = new HashMap<>();

   for(StructField field : fields) {
      accumulateurs.put(field.name(), ctx.longAccumulator(field.name()));
   }

   candidat.foreach((ForeachFunction<Row>)row -> {
      for(int index = 0; index < fields.length; index ++) {
         StructField field = fields[index];

         // Si le champ est nullable d'après le schéma et qu'on nous demande de l'ignorer, passer au suivant.
         if (ignorerNonNullables && field.nullable()) {
            continue;
         }

         // Détecter un champ null et le compter.
         if (row.isNullAt(index)) {
            accumulateurs.get(field.name()).add(1L);
         }
      }
   });

   // Convertir les nombres de champs nulls en pourcentages
   for(StructField champ : fields) {
      Long nombreDeNulsPourLeChamp = accumulateurs.get(champ.name()).value();
         tauxDeChampsNulls.put(champ.name(), (double)nombreDeNulsPourLeChamp / count);
   }

   // Trier par taux de nullité et ordre alphabétique
    tauxDeChampsNulls = tauxDeChampsNulls.entrySet().stream().sorted((a, b) -> {
      if (Objects.equals(a.getValue(), b.getValue()) == false) {
         return Double.compare(a.getValue(), b.getValue());
      }
      else {
         return a.getKey().compareTo(b.getKey());
      }
   }

   ).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));

   tauxDeChampsNulls.forEach((key, value) -> LOGGER.info("{} : {}", key, value));
   return tauxDeChampsNulls;
}
```

ends, correctly with this content:

```
Il y a 345935 enregistrements dans ce Dataset.
date_creation_ressource : 0.0
date_modification_ressource : 0.0
filetype_ressource : 0.0
id_catalogue : 0.0
id_ressource : 0.0
nombre_downloads_ressource : 0.0
prive_catalogue : 0.0
slug_catalogue : 0.0
titre_catalogue : 0.0
url_catalogue : 0.0
url_ressource : 0.0
titre_ressource : 0.0036654284764478877
id_organisation_catalogue : 0.02501336956364635
organisation_catalogue : 0.02501336956364635
licence_catalogue : 0.04796854900487086
format_ressource : 0.07015479786665126
archive_catalogue : 0.2990417274921589
description_ressource : 0.45873646783355254
mime_ressource : 0.4728287105959212
filesize_ressource : 0.843233555436715
checksum_type_ressource : 0.8453553413213465
checksum_valeur_ressource : 0.8453553413213465
moissonneur_date_modification_ressource : 0.880619191466605
moissonneur_date_creation_ressource : 0.9292959660051744
```

Which allow me to think that I can declare ten fields not nullable, filter one for few pathological values (`titre_ressource` that is exceptionally empty), and the others: nullable.